# How to show the data, show the loading screen, or report the error based State<T> in Android Studio Compose official sample project?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The following Code A is from the official [Advanced State in Jetpack Compose Codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

And I have read the [article](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#7).

1. In Code B, I think the value of `uiState.isLoading` should always `false` because either `DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)` or `DetailsUiState(throwError = true)` will get the object with the value `isLoading = false` by default, right?
2. I think that the business logic should be this:

   Loading screen is displayed first and `uiState.isLoading==true` when the data `ExploreModel` is loading.

   The data UI is displayed automatically and `uiState.cityDetails != null` when the data `ExploreModel` has been loaded.

   I run and test the Code A, the log of the project record *"Is Loading"* first, then record *"Have Data"*.

   But I can't understand how the code in the project can display loading screen first, then display data UI automatically again, could you tell me?

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    ...
) {
    val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true)) {
        val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
        value = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
            DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
        } else {
            DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Code A**

```
data class DetailsUiState(
    val cityDetails: ExploreModel? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val throwError: Boolean = false
)



@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    onErrorLoading: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true)) {
        val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
        value = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
            DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
        } else {
            DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
        }
    }

    when {
        uiState.cityDetails != null -> {
            Log.e("My","Have Data") //I add
            DetailsContent(uiState.cityDetails!!, modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
        uiState.isLoading -> {
            Box(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Log.e("My","Is Loading") // I add
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                )
            }
        }
        else -> { onErrorLoading() }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DetailsContent(
    exploreModel: ExploreModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
       ...
    }
}



class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val cityName = savedStateHandle.get<String>(KEY_ARG_DETAILS_CITY_NAME)!!

    val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel>
        get() {
            val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
            return if (destination != null) {
                Result.Success(destination)
            } else {
                Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
            }
        }
}


sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below line produces the initial State with isLoading true.

```
val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true))
```

This is the initial state with isLoading true.

```
DetailsUiState(
    cityDetails =null,
    isLoading = true,
    throwError = false
)
```

So initially It will show a CircularProgressBar.

Then the following code block will be executed.

```
    val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
    value = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
        DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
    } else {
        DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
    }
```

And either it will get data or produce an error.
If it is a success then the state will be like

```
 DetailsUiState(
    cityDetails = cityDetailsResult.data,
    isLoading = false,
    throwError = false
)
```

or Error

```
DetailsUiState(
    cityDetails = null,
    isLoading = false,
    throwError = true
)
```

In both success or error cases, isLoading is false so there will be no CircularProgressBar. Only the initial state will be with isLoading true. So initially, it will show a CircularProgressBar.

Comment: Thanks! I think the `fun DetailsScreen(..)`  will end after UI has shown a `CircularProgressBar` when  `val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true))`.

Comment: I can't understand why the project can display loading screen first, then display data UI automatically again, could you tell me?

Comment: because produceState returns a State object. So uiState is a state and whenever a state changes whoever using that state will run again. This is what compose does whenever a state changes it recomposes any UI element consuming that state.  And under the hood produceState uses LauncedEffect. So it is Side-Effects free.